# negative Euribor rates and stationary time series

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity

When we want to ensure stationary time series of Euribor, how to do this with a negative rates as we can't take the difference log of the variable when it is negative?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context and detail about your question?

Comment: some of the current interbank lending market rates are negative. therefore, it is not possible to take the difference log of the data to ensure  stationarity as we cant take the logarithm of negative real numbers).

Comment: please edit your question to include new information.

Comment: I would expect interest rates to be stationary. I would *not* expect the interest rate to contain a unit root.

Comment: the historical European three months interbank interest rates are not stationary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point of confusion may be what is meant by log returns or log interest rate.

Let's say you have a return or interest rate $R$ like -.01 or .02.

The *log return* is:

$$ r = \log\left(1 + R \right) $$

If you're doing time series analysis, it's often nice to work with log returns because summing log returns (and taking the exp) is equivalent to multiplying simple returns.

Also note that the log return is equivalent to the difference in log prices.

$$r_{t+1} = \log\left( \frac{P_{t+1}}{P_t} \right)  = \log P_{t+1} - \log P_t$$